# How to count the number of possible combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, enumerate

```
list0 = ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
list1 = ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
list2 = ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
list3 = ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
for x in list0:
      for y in list1:
            for z in list2:
                  for i in list3:
                        print(x,y,z,i)
```

I have been trying to generate a list of combined nucleotide sequences possible from 4 possible nucleotides.

I would like to either enumerate my output to be able to determine the number of combinations possible or else generate a count.

Comment: Have you tried `count = 0` outside the for-loops with `count += 1` all the way inside?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula for permutations with replacement:

```
num = 1
for lst in [list0, list1, list2, list3]:
    num *= len(lst)

print(num)
# 256
```

Comment: Is there any other way without using modules?

Comment: @rivendicato Yes. But modules make it easier.

Comment: @rivendicato `map` is a built-in function and does not require you to import any module, but why do you not want to use a module, especially if it's from the standard library?

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

I would prefer to learn the very basics first.

Answer (score 1):

You could enumerate the output using a simple counter variable.

```
list0 = ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
list1 = ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
list2 = ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
list3 = ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
count = 1
for x in list0:
      for y in list1:
            for z in list2:
                  for i in list3:
                        print(count,x,y,z,i)
                        count += 1
```